# Getting VR playspace in Godot and tracked area bounds

Tags: godot

With ARVROrigin you can get the center of the play space in the virtual world, but I would like to know how much space around the center the player has to work with. For this I would like to know the dimensions of the playspace and it's orientation (assuming it is a rectangle... not sure for Quest), and some sort of representation of the outer bounds of the tracked area. This way I can adjust the game experience based on where the player is in the physical environment.

I am thinking of taking advantage of the tracked area to put in walls in the space dynamically to create an infinite explorable building kinda like unseen diplomacy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `GodotVR` plugin you can fetch an array that represents the guardian boundries with the following code:

```
onready var ovrTrackingTransform = preload("res://addons/godot_ovrmobile/OvrTrackingTransform.gdns").new()
onready var ovrGuardianSystem = preload("res://addons/godot_ovrmobile/OvrGuardianSystem.gdns").new()

func _process(delta):
    print("GetTrackingSpace: " , ovrTrackingTransform.get_tracking_space())

    print("GetBoundaryVisible: ", ovrGuardianSystem.get_boundary_visible())
    print("GetBoundaryOrientedBoundingBox: ", ovrGuardianSystem.get_boundary_oriented_bounding_box())
```

Taken from https://github.com/GodotVR/godot_oculus_mobile

Comment: This is helpful, but only works for oculus mobile. Are there similar methods for Vive and Rift?

Comment: @RobKohr not yet in the godot plugin, but there is an open issue to add that functionality to the plugin [here](https://github.com/GodotVR/godot_openvr/issues/69) the methods already exist in OpenVR.